# How to find the first date in a set of available dated in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, momentjs

I have this line of code in an angularjs program:

```
ng-class="{ 
        today: day.isToday,
        'different-month': !day.isCurrentMonth, 
        'disabled': !day.isAvailable && !day.isAvailable, 
        'days': day.isAvailable 
    }"
```

The code is evaluating various properties of a day object to select a style sheet based on that evaluation. I am wondering if there is such a day property available that will allow me to select the first day (something like day.firstday) from the available set of days? if not, how can I fetch the first day from a set of available days? I would like to modify the above line as following, if possible:

```
ng-class="{ 
        today: day.isToday,
        'different-month': !day.isCurrentMonth, 
        'disabled': !day.isAvailable && !day.isAvailable, 
        'days': day.isAvailable, 
        'selection': day.isAvailable && day.firstday 
    }"
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Sorry, the subject line was supposed to be "How to find the first day in a set of available dates in angularjs?"

Comment: Side note: Why `'disabled': !day.isAvailable && !day.isAvailable` ? Why not just `'disabled': !day.isAvailable` ?

Comment: Also what is "the first day... from a set of available days". Where is this array coming from?

Comment: @igor disabled': !day.isAvailable && !day.isAvailable twice is a typo. Here is the previous line ng-click="select(day)" ng-repeat="day in week.days">
                            <div ng-class="{'selection':day.date.isSame(selected),'notselected-test':!day.date.isSame(selected),'selection': day.isAvailable}"

Comment: The array is coming from a directive and is available in html file in "day in week.days".

Comment: OK. I would create a method in the directive/component that you call and pass the current date to **or** set a property on it once when you initialize the array with the data.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use **moment.min**

Syntax : `moment.min(<List of dates>)`

```js
var a = moment().subtract(1, 'day');
var b = moment().add(1, 'day');
console.log(moment.min(a, b));  // a
console.log(moment.min([a, b])); // a
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

reference- https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/min/